# Delete Column if value does not equal in array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I was thinking that this might be done better as an array, but not sure how to do that. The way I am doing it now doesn't produce the results I am looking for:

```
Sub DeleteColumns_Cash()
Set dltRange = Range("A1:ZZ1")
For Each cell In dltRange
    If cell.Value <> "AMOUNT" Or cell.Value <> "TRANTYPE" Or cell.Value <> "CCY" Or cell.Value <> "SECID" Or cell.Value <> "SECDESC" Or cell.Value <> "FUND" Then
    cell.EntireColumn.Delete
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Two things.  When looking for what it is not then use `And` not `Or` in the if Statement.  Second, you will need to use a standards `For` loop and loop backwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub DeleteColumns_Cash()
    Dim arr
    arr = Array("AMOUNT", "TRANTYPE", "CCY", "SECID", "SECDESC", "FUND")
    Set dltRange = Range("A1:ZZ1")
    For Each cell In dltRange
        If IsError(Application.Match(cell.Value, arr, 0))  Then
            cell.EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The Line `Set dltRange = Range("A1:ZZ1")` has produced an error for me `Argument Not Optional`

Comment: Difficult to say what your problem is.  There's nothing missing in the line I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Change your conditional statement to a [Select Case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278665.aspx) and loop backwards.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteColumns_Cash()
    Dim i As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        With .Range("A1:ZZ1")
            For i = .Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
                Select Case LCase(.Cells(1, i).Value2)
                    Case "amount", "trantype", "ccy", "secid", "secdesc", "fund"
                        'do nothing
                    Case Else
                        .Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Delete
                End Select
            Next i
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Changing `With Activesheet` to `With Worksheets("xxxxxxx")` where *xxxxxxx* is the actual name of the worksheet to be processed is also recommended.